# Spring Data JPA - Different joins for different queries

Tags: java, json, serialization, spring-data-jpa, circular-reference

Using Java 11, Spring Boot, and Spring Data JPA

## Overview

I have 3 joined tables in a mysql database that I want to access using Spring Data JPA.  For the sake of simplicity, let's call them student, course, and performance_report.

Here are my data classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Data
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PerformanceReport> performanceReports;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
@Data
public class Course {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private Long courseId;

    @Column(name = "course_name")
    private String courseName;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "performance_report")
@Data
public class PerformanceReport {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "performance_report_id")
    private Long performanceReportId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
    // JsonBackReference needed to prevent infinite recursion.
    @JsonBackReference
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = false)
    private Course course;

    @Column(name = "grade")
    private String grade;

    @Column(name = "attendance")
    private String attendance;
}
```

Here is my StudentRepository:

```java
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    Optional<Student> findById(Long studentId);
}
```

Calling StudentRepository.findById produces an object like this:

```json
{
  "studentId": 1,
  "studentName": "Spongebob Squarepants",
  "performanceReports": [
    {
      "performanceReportId": 5473,
      "course": {
        "courseId": 643,
        "courseName": "Boating 101"
      },
      "grade": "F",
      "attendance": "100%"
    },
    {
      "performanceReportId": 4723,
      "course": {
        "courseId": 346,
        "courseName": "Grilling 101"
      },
      "grade": "A+",
      "attendance": "100%"
    }
  ]
}
```

## Problem

I also want to perform the inverse of this operation so I can query Course and get an object like this:

```json
{
  "courseId": 346,
  "courseName": "Grilling 101",
  "performanceReports": [
    {
      "performanceReportId": 4723,
      "student": {
        "studentId": 1,
        "studentName": "Spongebob Squarepants"
      },
      "grade": "A+",
      "attendance": "100%"
    },
    {
      "performanceReportId": 4774,
      "student": {
        "studentId": 4,
        "studentName": "Squidward Tentacles"
      },
      "grade": "C-",
      "attendance": "72%"
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot do this with my current entity structure.

If I set up the joins for `Course` in the same way as I do for `Student` - by adding a `@OneToMany` in `Course` and adding a `@JsonBackReference` to the second `@ManyToOne` in `PerformanceReport` -  I won't get any `Student` data in my result. It will also prevent the `Course` data from flowing through to the `Student` query.  If I remove the `@JsonBackReference` annotations, I get infinite recursion and a StackOverflow error.

I tried creating separate entities to account for these scenarios. I removed the join from the `Student` and put it in a class that extends `Student`. I then do the same for `Course` and `PerformanceReport`. Not only does this cause new errors, but it is very messy. It also requires me to create separate repositories for dealing with these extended classes.

There must be a better way.

Am I approaching this correctly?  Is Spring Data JPA the best way to accomplish such a task?  What if I want to query `Student` or `Course` without using any joins at all?

Surely I don't need new entities for every possible scenario.  How can I customize the way I join tables for different queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not so much related to JPA and can be expressed in a more compact way. I present and explain a solution that uses - instead of `@JsonBackrefence` - a `@JsonView` annotation.

Assume we have two classes:

**Parent**:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Parent {
    public static class ManagedReferenceView {};
    // Just to have something to show   
    private String name = "" + hashCode();
    @JsonView(ManagedReferenceView.class)
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

**Child**:

```
@Getter @Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Child {
    public static class BackReferenceView {
    };
    // Just to have something to show   
    private String name = "" + hashCode();
    @JsonView(BackReferenceView.class)
    private final Parent parent;
}
```

As you see the view classes need no code, those are just "names" to be used. The point is to tell what we want to serialize when. And this is how those are used (for example):

Construct some parent:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
p.setChildren(Arrays.asList(new Child(p), new Child(p)));
```

Serialize `Parent`:

```
objectMapper.writerWithView(Parent.ManagedReferenceView.class).writeValueAsString(p);
```

Serialize `Child`:

```
objectMapper.writerWithView(Child.BackReferenceView.class).writeValueAsString(p);
```

And for the JPA optimizing part of your question you can add `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to your joins which lets Hibernate to decide whether it is wise to fetch references from db. In best case references are not fetched until `objectMapper` needs to call getter for reference when serializing. And maybe you need a view also that does not trigger getter.

Also you can implement JPA projections and such but that is an another story.

Comment: Thank you.  It took a few attempts at researching and experimenting, but I finally got it to work with @JsonView.  Thank you for the answer!